# Subdivision surface smoothing only some edges

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am applying the Subdivision Surface modifier on the model of a queen chess piece. Does anyone know why some of the crown's horns are modified like in the second picture? The topology seems to be exactly the same for each individual horn. My desired outcome is for all the horns to remain pointy.

[image: Model without the Subdivision Surface modifier]

[image: Model with the Subdivision Surface modifier applied]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: it's quite strange that you have a vertex on the top of the horn.. you should have something like this: https://i.imgur.com/9R77K5m.png

Comment: @Sanbaldo Thanks, this solved my issue. Here's the result: https://imgur.com/a/P3TYaOt Nonetheless, I'm still curious if there's an explanation why the modifier behaved like that in the first case.

Comment: It seems like that the sharp horns have double vertices, try to remove them with merge by distance. Aft that us the knife tool to cut the horns close to the corner that will be enough to make them sharp.

Comment: @VeloFX I did something similar to that; link is in the post above. However there weren't any double vertices.

Comment: You likely have some geometry differences. I can't see the link to the file to check it out. Where it is?

Comment: @Carlo You can find the file here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Akg8JKao9Ulxh4BGumsudroPYKx6ww?e=seu4gO

Comment: @moonboots uploading to blend-exchange does not seem to work for me, the file simply doesn't get uploaded. If you want to get the file check my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your topology should not allow to have sharp tips, it's just because some of your faces are flipped that you get them sharp, if you recalculate the normals you'll have the same result:

[image]

To fix this, bring some edge loops with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did get the look I wanted by adding edge loops, but I was still curious why some horns remained sharp while others didn't in the first situation. I did not think about checking the normals.